# Struct name *ptr = (Same struct name *) p2;

Tags: c, pointers, structure

What is the meaning of this statement in C?

```
struct foo *ptr = (struct foo *) p2;
```

Comment: Syntax error... Where is this fragment from?

Comment: how it is ? I thinks its true

Comment: What is true? This code won't work as you put it here.

Comment: but its working for me !! just i didn;t understand it!

Comment: You have to give **ALL** the code, not one fragment.

Comment: if (ptr && p2->variable) {......}

Comment: ***"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking."***

Comment: @abelenky i just ask the meaning of this statement

Comment: Well it is clearly what he is asking, but it is just unanswerable without additional code.

Comment: Without seeing some information about the type and value of p2, we cannot answer.   Your comment: *if (ptr && p2->variable)* makes no sense in relation to the code you posted.

Comment: UINT32 p2; is the type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting at the left hand side:

```
struct foo *ptr
```

declares `ptr` to be of type `struct foo *`, that is a pointer to `struct foo`.

The `=` initializes that `ptr` variable to whatever the right hand side evaluates as.

And the right hand side

```
(struct foo *) p2
```

is an expression that casts `p2` to be of type `struct foo *`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not giving all the informations we need:

```
struct name *ptr = (Same struct name *) p2;
```

let's make it something that can compile:

```
struct foo* ptr = (struct foo*) p2;
```

but now we're missing what `p2` is. So, I'm going to assume that `p2` is a plain C pointer, i.e. `void*`:

```
void* p2;
struct foo* ptr = (struct foo*) p2;
```

So here you're assigning to `ptr` the address pointed by `p2`. In my example now, this is pretty pointless… but if you allocate some memory:

```
void* p2 = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
struct foo* ptr = (struct foo*) p2;
```

then `p2` is having the address of a memory space that then you assign to `ptr`.

The example I'm giving you here is using two variables for doing the usual:

```
struct foo* ptr = (struct foo*) malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
```

Comment: UINT32 p2; is the type

Comment: Since void* can be assigned to any pointer casting examples are kinda irrelevant.

Comment: [looks like it is considered to be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) though I've been taught to cast my mallocs at uni, and I think there are some compilers complaining about this when you do `-Wall`.

Comment: No C compiler should ever complain about casting from `void*`

Comment: Not if they are standard compliant. Casting is only useful when using C++ compiler for C code, which is a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: ok, good to know, Jori. Though there are some cases where you have a C++ compiler and the only way to allocate memory is to use `malloc()` (as new is not existing). I'm thinking of AVR embedded development. But I'd agree that's an exception…